# Setting the content of a span element,populated from a list using selenium

Tags: html, selenium

I am trying to set the content of a span element using selenium but seems it is not getting set as the value. The span field is a value which is filled in from a list as the user types in.

### Further details on the problem

1)Go to http://www.goeuro.es.
2)Tried setting the destination field as under:
  a)If the user types berlin in the destination field,it gets replaced by the text (this is getting populating from their js)

**Berlín Alemania**

I tried setting this using the following code.

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='$desktopSearchform']/div[1]/div[2]/d-departure-position/div/div/div/span[1]")
private WebElement fromSearchFieldSpan1;

@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='$desktopSearchform']/div[1]/div[2]/d-departure-position/div/div/div/span[2]")
private WebElement fromSearchFieldSpan2;
.
.
.
.
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Berlín'", fromSearchFieldSpan1);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Alemania'", fromSearchFieldSpan2);
```

When I tried with the above provided code,it seemed as it set the text as the title of the said fields as I was getting a input validation error upon submitting the page(as if these values were not entered at all).
Screenshot attached.[image]

I can't set the value of this field using sendKeys() since this is not a text field.

Any thoughts how this can be set using selenium web driver.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to handle `span` element while you should handle `input`. Try below code:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='$city']")
private WebElement fromSearchFieldSpan;

fromSearchFieldSpan.sendKeys('Berlin Alemania')
```

Comment: perfect.Thanks a lot @Andersson